# Wine on Mac via Homebrew

Tags: windows, homebrew, wine, gcc

I installed a Windows application on my Mac after successfully installing Wine via Homebrew. The application runs and seems to function correctly except that all of my data is missing. I get the following error when i run it:

```
Wine cannot find the ncurses library (libncurses.5.4.dylib).
```

I tried installing the following [ncurses formula](http://braumeister.org/repos/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/formula/ncurses) to no avail. Am i missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by "all of my data is missing"?

Comment: @echristopherson The program doesn't get installed. It's just an executable. On my Windows machine i run the program and see all my data loaded in from the dat files. When i run the program via wine none of the data is there almost as if it were my first time running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to install Wine from [here](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) and everything is now working when using this version of Wine. A little easier than setting it up myself.